# Why Collapsing toolbar is showing white space when collapsing?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout

Collapsing toolbar is showing white space when collapsing. When scrolling down, collapsing toolbar collapsing faster then scrollbar so there is a wired white gap(marked with blue line)  is created

when app is in the normal state

[image]

when app is in collapsing state, the collapsing toolbar is collapsing way to faster than scrolling the content, as a result, there is a wired white gap is created ( marked with blue line)

[image]

XML file

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:layout_scrollInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.0" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/background" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/image3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/image2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/image1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <!--<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/profile_image"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="100dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="100dp"-->
    <!--android:adjustViewBounds="false"-->
    <!--android:scaleType="centerCrop"-->
    <!--android:src="@drawable/profile"-->
    <!--app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"-->
    <!--app:civ_border_width="2dp"-->
    <!--app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"-->
    <!--app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />-->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeShareDrawable" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_primary" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Any answer or solution you got for this. ?

Comment: @AshokKumarS no